# ASP.Net adding skype icons not appearing for phone numbers

Tags: asp.net, skype, formview

I have a binding below and i'm trying to automatically add skype click to call. How can I do this without editing the datasource?

```
<td style="width: 250px">
     <asp:Label ID="Label_PhoneNumber" Text="callto://"+'<%# Bind("PhoneNumber") %>' runat="server">
     </asp:Label>
</td>
```

I know the above doesnt work, but when I display phone number I get this:

```
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder_Content_fvDealershipInformation_Label_PhoneNumber">
     (302) 555-1212
</span>
```

and skype doesnt activate click to call.  So I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The callto needs to be in a link:

```
<a href="callto://123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

Also, the Skype [click to call](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/click-to-call/) plug-in needs to be installed in the browser.